# docker-compose can't reset postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Whenever I try to run docker-compose up I am getting `PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization` I do not want this. I want to completely wipe my postgres database and reinitialize.

I've tried deleting every container, volume, and image on the docker client and I've tried `docker-compose down --volumes` . Both times I still get `PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization` .

This is my compose env:

```
# This is passed into postgres container for compose
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=db_pass
POSTGRES_USER=db_user
POSTGRES_DB=test_db
# For heroku
DATABASE_URL="postgres://db_user:db_pass@postgres:5432/test_db"
```

This is my compose.yml

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ~/apps/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .compose.env
      - .env
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/apps/postgres` directory is created when your container is created. The `volumes` parameter in the Docker Compose file maps a directory from the host file system to a directory within the container.

If you didn't delete the `/apps/postgres` directory, your database won't be cleared. You can delete the `/apps/postgres` directory ✅